# Run Android app on PC but outside of Emulator screen

Tags: android, emulator

I know we can Android apps on PC using emulator like Andy or Bluestack.

What I really want to know if there's a way to run the app using the emulator but outside of Emulator screen.

For example - I use fooview app which floats on screen and I want to run that on PC. Using the emulators, I'm able to run it but only inside the emulator's screen not PC GUI.

Answer (score 0):

No, this cannot be done.

Aside from the fact that I don't know an emulator that would expose its host to android in such manner, it would be nearly impossible to make it possible for an emulator that emulates a completely different OS to do that.

That said, most apps available for Android do have either a version for PC, or the PC has a program that works similar to that app on Android.

I looked at fooView, and I'm very sure there is a program out there that allows you to count your mouse clicks and keyboard presses, and even track how far your cursor traveled.